# Develop a program that will use a subprogram with type that calculates the average of the integers i, j, k, m

Tags: c

Develop a program that will use a subprogram with type that calculates the average of the integers i, j, k, m.

```
#include<stdio.h>
float media (int j, int i, int k, int m);
{
    int S;
    return(float(j+i+k+m)/4);
}
void main(void)
{
    float S;
    S=media(15,5,7,14);
    printf("media=%f",S);
}
```

That's what I made can you help me.

Comment: `int S;` is useless in *media*, add a `\n` at the end of your format to flush output. *main* returns an `int`, remove unexpected ';' at end of `float media ...` not `void`. What is your question ? What help you need ?

Comment: I the issue is that the correct C syntax is `return ((float)(j+i+k+m)) / 4;`. When asking a question, please ask a question.

Comment: `float media (int j, int i, int k, int m);` should be `float media (int j, int i, int k, int m)`

Comment: `float(j+i+k+m)` is C++, not C. If you are using C++, add the C++ tag to this question and remove the C tag. If you are using C, you need to change that code to use a cast.

Comment: i'm using c not c++ thx for help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several errors in your code:

you have an extra ';' at the end of

> ```
> float media (int j, int i, int k, int m);
> ```

*float* is not a function, you want a cast

*main* returns an `int`

*S* is useless in *media*

You want something like :

```
#include<stdio.h>

float media (int j, int i, int k, int m)
{
    return ((float) j+i+k+m)/4;
}

int main(void)
{
    float S=media(15,5,7,14);
    printf("media=%f\n",S);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
media=10.250000
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code have several issues.

1. `float media (int j, int i, int k, int m);` - Trailing `;` between function head and body as it is a function definition, not a prototype.
2. `return(float(j+i+k+m)/4)` - This is wrong regarding the C syntax. You need to separate the cast like `(float)` in C.
3. `int S;` in `media()` - This object is redundant.
4. The return value of `main` shall be `int`, not `void`.

---

Here is the corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float media (int j, int i, int k, int m)
{
    return (float) ((j + i + k + m) / 4);
}

int main(void)
{
    float S;
    S = media(15, 5, 7, 14);
    printf("media = %f", S);
}
```

Output:

```
media = 10.000000
```